# Получить значение по ключу из JSON строки

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Есть поле, которое хранит json текст. Внутри есть переменная id `{"Id":25680,"Code":...`. Нужно из json взять Id объекта и поместить значение в поле. Как вырезать значение Id? Кол-во цифр разное.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [JSON_VALUE(...)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (доступна начиная с SQL Server 2016):

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(field_name, '$.Id') FROM table_name
```