# Получить значение по ключу из JSON строки (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Продолжение [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858123/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Есть поле, которое хранит json текст. Внутри есть переменная id `{"Id":25680,"Code":....` Нужно из json взять Id объекта и поместить значение в поле. Как вырезать значение Id? Кол-во цифр разное.

**[Функция `JSON_VALUE` не поддерживается в SQL Server 2014](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через `substring`, если текст имеет одну и ту же структуру:

```
create table table1 (json varchar (200));
insert into table1 
values ('{"Id":25680,"Code":....')

select substring (json,charindex (':',json)+1,charindex (',',json)-charindex (':',json)-1)
from table1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ce6b/7)

Answer (score 1):

Извлечь заданый ключ (Id, Code или другой какой-то):

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(2000) = '{"Id":25680,"Code":...,'
    ,@key   VARCHAR(32)

SET @key = 'Id'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
@t, 
PATINDEX('%"'+@key+'":%', @t) + LEN('"'+@key+'":'),
CHARINDEX(',', @t, PATINDEX('%"'+@key+'":%', @t) + LEN('"'+@key+'":')) - (PATINDEX('%"'+@key+'":%', @t) + LEN('"'+@key+'":'))
)
```